# Allow a user group read, write, execute access to a particular directory

Tags: permissions

I want to grant a group **"usera"** rwx permission to a directory. The directory is already owned by a user that belongs to this group **"usera".** The name of the username and group is same.

**Current Permissions:**

If I check the current permissions of that directory by running the following command:

```
ls -la
```

Following is the output:

```
drwxrwsrwx 2 usera        usera        4096 Jan  9 09:30 .
```

Desired Output:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 usera        usera        4096 Jan  9 09:30 .
```

**Problem Statement:**

The problem is that the above-mentioned **usera** doesn't have ssh access to the server. So, I have to login via another user with admin privileges. And I want to grant group **"usera"** rwx permissions on a particular directory `/opt/test/abcd`. But I am unable to figure out which command to run. I know we can grant permissions by using `chmod` command but how to apply it in this context

Comment: Please update your question and include a description of what happens when you try to access the content in this directory.

Comment: The output you show, shows `rwx` permission. It also shows that the group currently has set-gid. Tell us what you are trying to achieve. Show us what you tried, and show us what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Only root (`sudo`) and the owner of a file can change the group and permissions of that file:

```
chgrp usera /opt/test/abcd
chmod g=rwx /opt/test/abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

The group `usera` already has group `rwx` permissions. The directory also has setgid privilege, which is why `s` is shown instead of `x` or `S`.

If you really want to remove the setgid bit you can do so,

```
chmod g-s the_directory
```